# Transition between the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let me try to explain my problem.

I have page which show list of documents. This page has next url for example:

```
GET /documents/1/2009/ HTTP/1.1" 200 126071
```

1 - category of the documents

2009 - year when documents was created

Every such document has button. When user click to that button he can see form to edit the data. After submit the form I update list of documents by ajax. Here is urls of that actions:

```
GET /documents/1/2009/edit/1120/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5755

POST /documents/1/2009/edit/1120/ HTTP/1.1" 200 169852
```

1120 - id of the document

Last 2 url I notice in terminal, in the same time in browser user see first url.

My problem start after update. I have a lot of ajax requests in main page (first url). But they don't work after list update. It happens cause of url. Any new requests are added to the third url. For example in terminal I notice this:

```
GET /documents/1/2009/edit/1120/?page=2&querystring_key=page HTTP/1.1" 200 5747
```

But it must be such url:

```
GET /documents/1/2009/?page=2&querystring_key=page HTTP/1.1" 200 5747
```

**QUESTION:**
Is there any way return to first url after successful completion of the third url?!

**main_template.html**

```
<div id="documents" class="dd">
        <ol class="dd-list">
            {% include page_template %}
        </ol>
    </div>

   {% block script %}
    {# START: AJAX request to endless pagination #}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function activatePagination(){
            $.endlessPaginate({
                paginateOnScroll: true,
                onCompleted: function(context, fragment) {
                    activateTooltip();
                }
            });
        }
        activatePagination();
    </script>
    {# END: AJAX request to endless pagination #}

   <script src="{% static 'js/documents/crud.js'%}"></script> {# CRUD JS #}
   {% endblock %}
```

**crud.js:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#document-modal").on("submit", ".document-edit-form", function(e) {e.preventDefault(); saveForm.call(this, "Data successfully updated");});

    var saveForm = function(success_message) {
        var form = $(this);
        var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: formData,
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.form_is_valid) {
                    // Update list of documents
                    $("#documents ol.dd-list").html(data.html_documents);

                    activatePagination();

                    // Hide modal
                    $("#document-modal").modal("hide");

                    // Show message to user
                    $("#user-action-message").fadeIn("slow");
                    setTimeout(function() {$("#user-action-message").fadeOut("slow");}, 2000);
                }
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        });
        return false;
    };
});
```

Comment: Please post what code you have tried, and specific code examples. In short, yes there are always ways of doing most anything but without knowing specifics of your code we have no idea what you are looking for a solution to. If it is a one page template just save the desired url locally somewhere (like an array), then reload as needed and pass in as a parameter to the desired xhr request. There is also the concept in programming of singleton objects that store a registry of every object in a program use a singleton object to keep a registry of everything if need be.

Comment: @MatthewLagerwey Hello! :) I add my code. In `main_template.html` file you can see `activatePagination` function which works fine when user in first url but it don't work after list update by ajax. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: // Update list of documents
                    $("#documents ol.dd-list").html(data.html_documents);

                    activatePagination(); this is the line that isn't working correct?

Comment: `$("#documents ol.dd-list").html(data.html_documents);` works correctly. It update the list. `activatePagination();` don't work. I think problem with url adress.